# Testing chef data bags

Tags: chef-infra

I need to test chef recipe. This is using a data bag.

`kitchen` is using `chef_zero` in order to provision the machine. So, it's not able to get my data bag hosted on server. Then it's telling me that my data bag is not available.

How could I get a data bag available on test kitchen?

I've created a `aws.json` file on `test\integration\data_bags`:

```
{
  "id": "dev",
  "aws_access_key_id": "----",
  "aws_secret_access_key": "----"
}
```

When I perform my converge I'm getting this message:

> INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/data/aws/dev
>
> ERROR: Failed to load data bag item: "aws" "dev"

`.kitchen.yml` file content:

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  always_update_cookbooks: true

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-16.04
  - name: centos-7.2

suites:
  - name: default
    data_bags_path: "test/integration/data_bags"
    run_list:
      - recipe[living-development::default]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/smoke/default
    attributes:
```

Versions:

```
$ vagrant -v
1.9.2

$ chef -v
Chef Development Kit Version: 1.2.22
chef-client version: 12.18.31
delivery version: master (0b746cafed65a9ea1a79de3cc546e7922de9187c)
berks version: 2017-03-08T11:19:04.643719 5824] 2017-03-08T11:19:04.643719 5824] 2017-03-08T11:19:04.643719 5824] 2017-03-08T11:19:04.643719 5824] 2017-03-08T11:19:04.700789 5824] 2017-03-08T11:19:04.700789 5824] 5.6.0
kitchen version: 1.15.0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server error indicates that is searching something called `aws/dev` (where `aws` is the data bag's name and `dev` is the name of the item within that data bag).

So you would have to place your JSON file under `test/integration/data_bags/aws/dev.json`.

Btw. you don't have to manually specify the `data_bags_path`, as test-kitchen will search for items at exactly this path.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKing. As far I've been able to figure out, you are suggesting me that I remove `data_bags_path`? I've already tested it without specifying `data_bags_path` and it kept failing...

Comment: Specifying the default is just not needed :) You could have a look at our repos, like [this one](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/site-proxytypo3org). But your real problem is that you need a folder named `aws` with a file called `dev.json`. Not a file called `aws.json`.